# Why is fresh asphalt dark

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, visible-light

I have read that it is a mixture of bitumen and aggregate, stones and fillings.
But it does not explain why it get darker with time, is it the water so when it gets drier, it gets brighter? Or is ot temperature?

Question:

1. Why is fresh asphalt dark, and why does it get brighter with time/usage?
2. Is the explanation on the classical vs QM level different?

Comment: Though I don't know the specifics, it's most likely that the layer of dark bitumen on top is gradually worn off to reveal the lighter aggregate. No QM needed, just tribology.

Comment: Probably a question better suited for Chemistry SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fresh asphalt pavement is black because all the particles in it are covered with a layer of fresh tar.

With time, the tar gets covered with road dust and grit, and the topmost surface of the pavement gets the tar worn off to expose the aggregate. both these effects lighten the surface color.

The question of classical physics versus QM does not enter into the explanation.